# Call a MobaXterm command from a bash script

Tags: bash, command, mobaxterm

From my /home/mobaxterm command prompt, I can use the newtab "*command*" to launch a new tab and execute a command just fine. When I use it inside a bash script, I get "newtab: command not found".

Is there special coding required to use the MobaXterm commandline parameters as found here: https://blog.mobatek.net/post/mobaxterm-command-lines/ inside a bash script?
Thanks.

Comment: I deleted my answer so hopefully someone else can help you with that. I suggest that you add your comments to your post. Upvoted your post.

Answer (score 1):

Use this
`/bin/MobaSendMsg.exe MobaXterm -newtab "YOUR_COMMAND"`